# Python pandas tolist() not returning a list but [[]]

Tags: python, pandas

Why is the tolist() method not returning a list in my case, but something looking like the following?

> Loaded metadata for ShotID: 007_0030
>   [['007_0030', '01.02.2018', '1001-1085', '28 mm', 'T. 4', '10 m', 'Super 35', 'Sony FS7', 'Zeiss Ultra Prime', '30', '172.8°', 'dolly', '', '', '', '']]

```
def loadshotinfo(self, df, shotid):
    ix = df['Shot#'].loc[df['Shot#'].str.contains(shotid)].index
    metadatalist = df.values[ix].tolist()
    print('Loaded metadata for ShotID: ' + shotid)
    print(metadatalist)
```

I thought that values returns an array and tolist() makes a list out of it, so why does the console put out something like [['lsdjasd','gjasvdj']] when a list should look like ['..','..']?

---

Solved: tolist() actually returns a list of lists.

Comment: You are correct. I haven't really understood that these concepts yet, but thank you for the help! :)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataFrame is a table. `.tolist()` returns a list of lists, one list per row. If you have only one row, extract it with `df.values[ix].tolist()[0]`.